# line brek error with search system in php

Tags: php, search, system

I am developing a system that searches for words that the user types in php files, using PHP without MySQL but I am having a problem. The system works really well when there is not a line break in the file. For example, if I search for the word "good" in a file that contains the text "good morning" works fine, but if I search for "good" in a file that contains the text "good
morning" (with a line break) it won't list the file as a result. Here is my code:
index.php

```
<form action="busca.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="s"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

busca.php

```
<?php
$pesq = (isset($_GET['s'])) ? trim($_GET['s']) : '';
if (empty($pesq)) {
    echo 'Type something.';
} else {
    $index    = "index.php";
    $busca    = glob("posts/content/*.php", GLOB_BRACE);
    $lendo    = "";
    $conteudo = "";
    foreach ($busca as $item) {
        if ($item !== $index) {
            $abrir = fopen($item, "r");
            while (!feof($abrir)) {
                $lendo = fgets($abrir);
                $conteudo .= $lendo;
                $lendo .= strip_tags($lendo);
            }
            if (stristr($lendo, $pesq) == true) {
                $dados    = str_replace(".php", "", $item);
                $dados    = basename($dados);
                $result[] = "<a href=\"posts/$dados.php\">$dados</a>";
                unset($dados);
            }
            fclose($abrir);
        }
    }
    if (isset($result) && count($result) > 0) {
        $result = array_unique($result);
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($result as $link) {
            echo "<li>$link</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No results';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is wrong: `$lendo .= strip_tags($lendo);`. Should be `$lendo = strip_tags($lendo);`. Any why bother with loops when you can easily load a file into a variable with `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: where should I use file_get_contents()? I guess the loops are necessary for the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `stristr` is incorrect.
Compare it with `false` like this:

```
if (stristr($lendo, $pesq) !== false) {
```

If a string is located — the function returns the substring. Which can be casted as boolean `true` or `false`, you never know. If it doesn't find it — it returns `false` — the only correct value you should compare it to.

Even better to use `strpos` for this.
My variant:

```
foreach ($busca as $item) {
        if ($item !== $index) {
            $lendo = file_get_contents($item);
            $lendo = strip_tags($lendo);
            if (strpos($lendo, $pesq) !== false) {
                $dados    = str_replace(".php", "", basename($item));
                $result[] = "<a href=\"posts/$dados.php\">$dados</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```

To fix the linebreaks - try to get rid of them
Like this:

```
$lendo = file_get_contents($item);
$lendo = strip_tags($lendo);
$lendo = str_replace(["\r","\n"], ' ', $lendo);
```

Comment: Nice tip, but it still doesn't work with line breaks

Comment: Check the code again. Look what you do in a loop: ` $lendo = fgets($abrir);`  You replace $lendo with each and every line of the code. Not add but **replace**. At the end of your `while` it will contain the last line **only**. This is why much better to use `file_get_contents`, too. Less chance to add a bug like this